# Connect user to Firebase from front and back

Tags: angularjs, node.js, http, firebase, firebase-authentication

Here is my case :

- I have a front-end (AngularJS) with a connection to Firebase, and I user the firebase auth to authenticate users.
- For some special action (for example some time I need to send an email to the user), I have to call a webservice (NodeJs), which query Firebase, using [firebase-admin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start) package
- Currently this webservice isn't protected by authentication

**So my question is how can I handle front and back user authentication with Firebase ?**

How can I get the Firebase auth cookie then send it to my webservice to auth my user ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase provides some documentation on how to [verify ID tokens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens). To retrieve the ID token within your client-side Angular code, you can do this:

```
firebase.auth().currentUser.getToken(/* forceRefresh */ true).then(function(idToken) {
  // Send token to your backend via HTTPS
  // ...
}).catch(function(error) {
  // Handle error
});
```

And to verify the idToken on the server:

```
// idToken comes from the client app (shown above)
admin.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken)
  .then(function(decodedToken) {
    var uid = decodedToken.uid;
    // ...
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle error
  });
```

Comment: Thanks it's exactly what I need. I would have found it by myself, but the firebase documentation is a little bit messy